# Search and filter in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
tune = input("Type your tune parameters ?")
```

[image]

Hi there

I'm wondering if I can plot "High" on a line chart using,

When the program is triggered, the program will ask for an input, what I wanna do there is type somethign like "High*" so that it captures all tune with "High" in its name like High and HighCSS while looking for match.

Can this be done Python and Pandas ?  It is like searching for all the filename that starts with letter "a" with jpg as an extension in command prompt (dir a*.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

```
dataset : 

tune,drs
Low,31
Low-medium,42
Ultra Low,52
Medium,48
MediumHard,9
MediumSoft,26
MediumCSS,28
HightCSS,59
HightCSS,59
Avavee,34
Hight,22
Hight,49
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("ExportCSV.csv", usecols=["tune","drs"])
print("Enter a value of tune col..")
str = input()
is_found = df["tune"] == str
print(df[df["tune"].str.contains(str)])
```

For example, I entered the value of "Hig":

```
        tune  drs
7      Hight   53
8   HightCSS   59
10     Hight   22
13     Hight   49
```

Comment: Not this. 

I've a string input variable. Just by typing into input variable "tune", can you multiselect or keyword select for output?

Comment: You must enter the input string instead of the word 'Rooxo'

Comment: What would you type in when prompted by input to enter a word? It has to capture High, HighCSS and HighMedium ?

Comment: I created a test database and used it, you replace your database and enter the desired word in the input.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Nevermind.